# What are the characteristics of goal posts in football?

Tags: rules, football, equipment

How many types of goal posts are there in football, and what materials are used to construct them? What are the dimensions of the goals?

Comment: hate to be a critic, but should this question not have been searched for on the internet, ie. the answer is easly found on google.

Comment: The majority of questions asked on this site regarding rules of a sport can be easily found by searching for the rulebook and sifting through it. It's not an outstanding question, but it's driving people here directly to the answer from web searches which makes it easier for them to find information.

Answer (score 8):

According to [FIFA's Laws of the game <sup>PDF</sup>](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/27_06_2014_new--lawsofthegameweben_neutral.pdf)

The size of the goalpost is 7.32 m (8 yds) x 2.44 m (8 ft).

> The distance between the posts is **7.32 m (8 yds)** and the distance from the 
>   lower edge of the crossbar to the ground is **2.44 m (8 ft)**.

[image: Goalpost size]
<sup>Source: [fifa.com](http://www.fifa.com)</sup>

Other characteristics (taken from the same law):

> A goal consists of two upright posts equidistant from the corner ﬂagposts and 
>   joined at the top by a horizontal crossbar. **The goalposts and crossbar must 
>   be made of wood, metal or other approved material**. They must be square, 
>   rectangular, round or elliptical in shape and must not be dangerous to players.

Comment: I find it interesting how the measurements are made using feet and yards, instead of meters. Note how the metric units are decimals and the imperial units are whole. Nearly the whole world uses the metric system, so it seems out of place.

Comment: I don't really know how you'd fix that, given the game is accustomed to a goal of that size. 2.5m x 7.5m seems like a big change for the game for the sake of making measurement easier.

Comment: @hims056 I don't know your source, but I think it's too old: As far as I know, the posts and the crossbars have to be round (at least without edges). There were too much head injuries when players (goalkeepers) run against them. For this square or rectangular posts are classified as dangerous for players now.
Even wooden posts are, because of the splinters.
Nevertheless there are still enough fields with wooden rectangular posts. But never in modern stadiums or fields with league action.

Comment: @hims056 is correct - his source is the current (2014/15) FIFA Laws of The Game. For higher level matches, it may be stipulated that the goals are round and made of metal in the competition rules, but it's definitely not a base requirement.

Comment: With regards to the measurements, feet and yards are always used in football, as the game originates from England. Another example is the distance to the ball on set pieces, which is 9,15 meters (=10 yards?). Old habits die hard ;) Some might even call it "tradition"!